# Can executeQuery and executeBatch be used simultaneously with one connection for each?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, batch-processing

I have a use case where in I need to process some queries in batch ( stmt.addBatch() ) and some queries need to be executed as soon as they are created (stmt.executeQuery() ) because their result will be used in the queries going for batch processing. The database is (obviously) common for both. My question is can I keep two open connections throughout for the above use case ? Will that be a good idea considering consistency & viability in mind ?

Edit : What if the queries in question were to act upon different records, can 2 simultaneous active connection objects be kept alive for handling each scenario ?

P.S. - I am relatively new to backend & databases specifically, request you to include some explanation / further reading pointers for the same.

Comment: no, how can a database else keep track of the updated data, it will lock a row or table and then when the lock is released the second can do its task

Comment: If you are worried about consistency, I would look into JDBC Transactions.

Comment: @nbk I see. By the way, is it possible to have two simultaneous active connection objects one for batch processing and the other for immediate execute ? Assuming the queries will not be working upon the same records.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it is basically not predictable which will start first as also processors can shift commands  ad risc level.

in a view of a rdms, you can have simultaneous access to the same table/ row for that you can read more about [locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html)

for a executebatch is one transaction for the hole batch, so if it would start first, your single command would be locked out, till the lock was lifted, and then proceed if not the timeout hits first.

so for one rdms the consistency is guaranteed, for replicated system it  gets more [complicated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-replication-configuring-consistency-guarantees.html)

Oh I see an edit:

Row level locks are mentioned in the first link, which would answer your edit also: